# expressjs render html file without any engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to nodejs and expressjs 
I am trying to develop a simple login page which has a username field and a password inside a form. on submit of the form i will redirect the user to a home page where i will display the message welcome user- userName. I want both the login and home pages to be simple html files. The form in login page has action set to home.html so when the user submits the form i can get the user name and password using res.body.userName and res.body.password. My question is how to use express to render html file. I do know that i can use res.sendfile function to send a html file but sendfile function does not support sharing variables to the html file. 
I have posted below my code in app.js

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.all("/",function(req,res,next){
    res.render("login.html");
});
app.all("/home.html",function(req,res,next){
    res.render("home.html",{"userName":req.body.userName});
})
http.createServer(app).listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Listening at port 3000");
})
```

Comment: For this you will need a rendering engine such as jade or ejs

Comment: HTML isn't a templating language, just purely markup. EJS is the closest thing to plain HTML with the ability to add variables.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a rendering engine to serve up static assets like html files. You should rethink what is being served up on different request but for what you want you have to place your static assets in a directory and tell express where they are like so

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Assuming your server file is on the root, and you have an `public` folder on the root as well, put your html files in the folder. By default, express will look for an `index.html` file in the foot of that public folder and serve it on a `GET` request to `/`. You are overriding that by serving your login page. That's fine. You have to use `res.sendfile('/path/to/file')` instead of `res.render()`